# Изменение даты на следующий день

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Есть вывод сегодняшней числа и месяца

```js
var now = new Date();
var textout;
var month = now.getMonth();
var date = now.getDate();
textout = date;
if (month == 0) textout += " января";
if (month == 1) textout += " февраля";
if (month == 2) textout += " марта";
if (month == 3) textout += " апреля";
if (month == 4) textout += " мая";
if (month == 5) textout += " июня";
if (month == 6) textout += " июля";
if (month == 7) textout += " августа";
if (month == 8) textout += " сентября";
if (month == 9) textout += " октября";
if (month == 10) textout += " ноября";
if (month == 11) textout += " декабря";

document.write("<br><div id='gdata' style='padding-top: 4px;'> " + textout + "</div>");
```

Как написать условие, что если текущее время больше 20:00, то выводить следующий день. Например сегодня 21 ноября, но после 20:00 число будет 22 ноября.

Comment: 1. Не используйте `document.write()`; 2. Зачем вам нужно это делать?

Comment: *если текущее время больше 20:00, то выводить следующий день* `значение = дата(now() + 4 часа)`

Comment: а метод `getHours()` чем-то не подходит ? и + не делайте вагон условий, сделайте массив с названиями месяцев и выводите нужное по индексу текущего месяца

Comment: массив я переделаю! да я понимаю, что надо использовать getHours(), просто не могу догнать, как правильно написать условие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С использованием метода метода [`getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) можно сделать так :

```js
var months = ['января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня', 'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря'];

var now = new Date();
if (now.getHours() >= 7) {
  now.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
}
   
var date = now.getDate();
var textout = date + ' ' + months[now.getMonth()];

document.write("<br><div id='gdata' style='padding-top: 4px;'> " + textout + "</div>");
```

ПС: в примере взял 7 часов, для наглядности.

Comment: Не нужны тут условия. См. комментарий от Akina

Comment: @tutankhamun согласен, но можно и так и так сделать

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych переменную `textout` можно объявить и присвоить ей значение в одном месте, а не в двух разных.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin ну а можно и вовсе не обьявлять :)

Comment: document.write - это очень плохо, на столько плохо, что например Chrome с 55 версии блокирует его при определенных обстоятельствах.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var date = new Date();

var month = new Array("января", "февраля", "марта", "апреля", "мая", "июня", "июля", "августа", "сентября", "октября", "ноября", "декабря");

var time = date.getTime();

console.log(date);

// для примера + 24 часа
var timeNew = time + (24 * 1000 * 60 * 60);

var dateNew = new Date(timeNew);

console.log(dateNew);

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('date-online');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].innerHTML = '<span>' + dateNew.getDate() + " " + month[dateNew.getMonth()] + '</span>';
}
```

```html
<div class="date-online"></div>
<div class="date-online"></div>
```

Comment: возможно, проще было бы искать элемент по `Id`, раз уж его можно найти в условии, и избежать использование цикла, тем более, что таких элементов может быть больше чем один.

Comment: @Sergey Glazirin  добавил, если таких блоков может быть больше чем один